# How does ramification groups help to study ramifications of local field extension?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

I am studying higher ramification groups of local field extension.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group) it is mentioned that higher ramification groups gives information about ramification of extension.

Suppose $L/K$ be a Galois extension of local field with decreasing filtration $$G_{-1}:=G \supset G_0 \supset G_1 \supset \cdots $$
It is given that

- $G_{0}$ is trivial iff $L/K$ is unramified
- $G_1$ is trivial iff $L/K$ is tamely ramified.

I think $G_0=G$ iff $L/K$ is totally ramified.

So it seems the first $3$ filtrations of $G$ is enough to say whether a local field extension is totally ramified or unramified or tamely ramified or wildly ramified.

Ami I right ?

But I am lacking motivation how exactly the ramification groups help to study ramifications because it seems harder to compute $G_0, G_1, \cdots$ practically.

So my question would be-

> Can you write (or list) some examples of local field extensions (eg., $p$-cyclotomic extension) where one can talk about ramifications by computing the ramification groups by hand ?

I indeed want to understand example of local field extension where one can compute the first few ramification groups ($G_{-1},G_0, G_1, \cdots)$ and thereby making conclusion whether the extension is unramified/totally ramified.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Try $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^f-1},p^{1/m},\zeta_{p^n}),G=Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ with $p$ odd and $m|p^f-1$.

Comment: @reuns, Can you please write an answer of your example because I have no prior concept to calculate the ramification groups ? I want to understand one example how computing the ramification groups helps us to say whether an extension is unramified/totally ramified

Comment: The first step is to find an uniformizer $\pi_K$ of $K$ and its residue field. Do you know an uniformizer of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^f-1},p^{1/m})$ ? Do you see what is the obvious guess for the residue field $O_K/(\pi_K)$ of $K$ ?

Comment: @reuns, I know the uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ is $\pi_1=\zeta_{p^n}-1$ while the uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^f-1}, p^{1/m})$ is $\pi_2=\frac{\zeta_{p^f-1}-1}{\sqrt{p} \cdots \sqrt[m-1]{p} \cdot \sqrt[m]{p}}$. I am not sure for the later one. Finally, the uniformizer for the residue field $O_K/(\pi_K)$ is the image of $\pi_K$ under the canonical map $O_K \twoheadrightarrow O_K/(\pi_K)$.

Comment: The uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^f-1}, p^{1/m})$ is just $p^{1/m}$. The point is that it has valuation $1/m$ with $p\nmid m$. What is the valuation of $\zeta_{p^n}-1$ ? $O_K/(\pi_K)$ is a finite field, it doesn't have an uniformizer but a cardinality and a primitive $q-1$-th root of unity that lifts to $K$ (Hensel lemma).

Comment: The valuation of $\zeta_{p^n}-1$ is $\frac{1}{p^n-1}$. Is it enough to find an uniformizer of your $K$ ? For an uniformizer of the extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ would have valuation equal to $\frac{1}{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$. I think the valuation of an uniformizer $\pi$ of $K$ would be linear comnination to that $1/m$ and $1/(p^n-1)$.

Comment: In Local Fields, Serre computes the ramification groups of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin, thanks for your comment. Indeed I am seeking an example of local field extension in which  one can talk about totally ramified/unramified  by computing the first few ramification group $G_0, G_1, \cdots.$